# Redirect Flow to newly created record from List View

Tags: visual-workflow, aura, list-view

I made a flow who simply create a new Cutom Object's record where the user fill a screen component with the information of the future record.

I had a first problem where my flow won't stop after clicking on "Finish" button and so start over again.

I tried making a second Screen who use an aura component who should redirect to the new record.

My component :

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction, lightning:availableForFlowScreens, lightning:availableForFlowActions">
   <aura:attribute name="recId" type="String" />
</aura:component>
```

The controller :

```
({    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
   // Get the record ID attribute
   var record = component.get("v.recId");
   
   // Get the Lightning event that opens a record in a new tab
   var redirect = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
   
   // Pass the record ID to the event
   redirect.setParams({
      "recId": record
   });
        
   // Open the record
   redirect.fire();
}})
```

The design file :

```
<design:component>
   <design:attribute name="recId" label="Record ID" />
</design:component>
```

In my flow I retrieve the new record's Id and use it in my last screen :

[image: screend flow that should redirect]

Even with that my flow wont end and start over without redirecting to the newly created record. This flow is use in a ListView ButtonList using my Flow's URL. So this is not a Quick Action or a Custom Button, strangely ListView doesn't find Quick Actions using a Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_finish_override.htm&type=5):-

> Local actions that fire force or lightning events might not work
> properly when you run the flow from:
>
> 1. Flow Builder
> 2. Flow detail pages or **list views**
> 3. Web tabs
> 4. Custom buttons and links

Instead, test and distribute the flow with a Lightning page, Experience Builder page, flow action, or utility bar. Your developer can also add the appropriate event handlers directly to the component.

As a workaround, you need to add an [value Init event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueInit/documentation). This event is fired when when an app or component is initialized, prior to rendering. Handle this event using the aura:handler tag.

Your component looks like:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction, lightning:availableForFlowScreens, lightning:availableForFlowActions">
   <aura:attribute name="recId" type="String" />
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

and your controller will look this:-

```
({    
   doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
   
   // Get the record ID attribute
   var record = component.get("v.recId");
   
   // Get the Lightning event that opens a record in a new tab
   var redirect = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
   
   // Pass the record ID to the event
   redirect.setParams({
      "recId": record
   });
        
   // Open the record
   redirect.fire();
}}
```

The init event will fire the event irrespective of where you are invoking the flow from.

Comment: The flow doesn't work but now I got the problem. I will create a record from an Aura Component it will be easier